# Steps to remove node from percona cluster

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, galera

I have to update the os on a few servers and I need to remove a db from the cluster.

```
wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://192.168.2.59,192.168.2.60,192.168.2.61,192.168.2.62,192.168.2.63'
```

Do I remove the ip adress from the cluster line then restart each node?
Or do I stop the service on the server I want to remove from the cluster then remove the ip address on the other nodes then restart the mysql service?

Comment: What is the goal?  To change from a 5-node cluster to 4-node?  To simulate a crash of one node?  To do some maintenance of the one node?  (The answer to your question depends on the goal.)

Comment: The goal is to upgrade from mysql 5.7 to 8 as well as upgrade my OS.  I believe I will also need to upgrade galera (unsure on this). The upgraded server I will make a cluster to see if upgrade was successful. If successful I will upgrade the other servers.

Answer (score 0):

To work on upgrading a node, this is probably the 'right' approach:  pretend that the node crashed.

1. Stop MySQL (on the one node).
2. Upgrade Percona-MySQL and/or OS.
3. Restart MySQL.  At this point, the one node will announce that is has 'recovered'.  The 5 nodes will have a conference and decide which of the 4 will help the 1 get back in sync.  Maybe via IST, probably SST.

I don't think there is any need to change the wsrep settings.

Answer (score -1):

as addition to answers above,
since you will upgrade the OS and the DB, it's good if you also :

- **test it first** at local VM. Preferably with full or subset of the data. Some settings and config at the OS or DB might be obselete and changed.
- do **full backup** before doing anything at the production server. Always create ways to revert all actions if something going wrong.