# Permanent node removal from Percona cluster

Tags: percona, galera

There are instructions about temporary removal a node from Galera, for backup, upgrade or testing.
But I couldn't find a safe step-by-step procedure for *permanent* removal.

I have a cluster with 4 nodes.

1. I issue `mysqladmin shutdown` on the node to remove.
2. Supposedly, I remove the node's address from `wsrep_cluster_address` on random live
   node, then I restart mysqld, then repeat this on other nodes?

[[1]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301873/steps-to-remove-node-from-percona-cluster) Related question, but without step-by-step procedure.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You have the procedure as part of your "question"; does it not do what you want? And why do you think that restarting the remaining nodes is necessary?

Comment: I ask is this procedure correct and full. I don't know how to fix cluster size and wsrep peer list without restarting.